# Is Cohen's $d$ a better measure of effect-size than a simple mean difference for a meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, standardization

Cohen's $d$ measures the difference between the mean for the experimental group and the control group divided by standard deviation. The Cohen's $d$ statistic produces something that does not add any value to the observed effect-size i.e. the difference between the mean for the experimental group and the mean of  control group.Should we use  Cohen's $d$ or simple difference produced by a controlled experiment for a meta-analysis?

Comment: The effect size measure Cohen's *d*?

Comment: Cohen's d-statistics is the difference between two means scaled by the standard deviation. The idea is to have a measure of effect size not dependent on the magnitude of the variable.

Comment: "d statistic" is what?  Cohen's, Durbin-Watson, Tajima, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Hoeffding's, Cook's, Somers, something else?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. If you would like your question answered, though, it will be necessary to edit it accordingly: most readers will not take the time or effort to read through these comments in order to figure out what you might be asking.

Comment: Could you please edit it ?

Comment: Does S.D. stand for 'standard deviation' or 'simple difference'? Ordinarily I'd assume the first, but since you are talking about 'simple difference' several times, it has become ambiguous.

Comment: I think that it Cohen's d simply misleads. It does not add anything to the correct interpretation of effect-size. Dividing by S.D. should generate a value that can not be explained in meaningful words. The S. D. is average distance from the mean. It simply changes the locus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is common to use simple (unscaled) mean differences to understand and communicate experimental results.  Furthermore, it is permissible to use them in meta-analyses.

In meta-analyses, however, mean differences are rarely used.  The reason is that studies often measure effects using different (incommensurate) scales.  If one study were conducted using degrees Fahrenheit and another using degrees Celsius, this would not be a problem, because there is a known conversion between these measures.  Often, however, there is not a known conversion.  Thus, *standardizing* the mean difference by dividing by the standard deviation eliminates the original units and denotes the effect in units of standard deviation instead.  This makes the measure more universal, and makes disparate studies comparable.

As a result of these facts, Cohen's $d$ is often used to communicate experimental results as well (that is, Cohen's $d$ is often used outside of meta-analyses).  It can be easier for people to understand.  This is especially true if people are likely to be unfamiliar with the scale used in the study.  Of course, if people would be very familiar with the measurements used, it may be better to retain the original scale for communicative purposes.

Note that dividing by the standard deviation is just a type of *rescaling*.  Rescaling does not change the nature of the information; the result cannot be more or less correct.

Answer (score 4):

Cohen's d is a measure of effect size.  Standard deviation is a measure of spread.

The standard deviation is used in calculating Cohen's d, but other than that there is very little relation - they measure different things, they require different input and they answer different questions.